# How to move my Realm file in SD card?

Tags: java, realm

How to move my Realm file in SD card?

And not just move, but also to connect to my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm also has constructors for opening any file: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#getInstance-java.io.File-java.lang.String-

So something like this should work:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

And remember to add this to your manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Also not all phones has a SD card and it might not be mounted so you will need additional checks for that if you don't want to encounter lots of weird crashes in production: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Thank you all turned out! And for your alert thank you!