# Show AlertDialog once after app has launched 3 times

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

How can I show an AltertDialog after 3 launches once?
I only know how to do something at the first start of the App(I am a beginner with Android and Sharedpreferences):

```
if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {
     Log.d("Comments", "First time");

     // Action which is done at first launch
     // save first launch
     settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit();
} else {
     //not first time          
}
```

Thank's, Felix

Comment: What you tried so far felix ?

Comment: I am a beginner, so I have only worked once with sharedpreferences in a first time task.

Comment: each time it is shown, increment and save to sharedpref and read before showing

Comment: Please check out this article before asking another question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by updating sharedPreferences by 1 and check if it is equal to 3, if it is then show alertDialog.

Here is an rough example.

In your `onCreate` method, add this:

```
int appLaunchedFor = getSharedPreferences("app_info", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("counter", 0);

if (appLaunchedFor == 3) {
    // Launch AlertDialog;

    // Now increment by 1 so that alertDialog will not launch again.
    getSharedPreferences("app_info", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("counter", ++appLaunchedFor).commit();
} else if (appLaunchedFor < 3) {
    getSharedPreferences("app_info", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("counter", ++appLaunchedFor).commit();
}
```

Comment: I get an Error for the operator == in line 3 and for (String,int)
in SharedPreferences cannot be applied to (String) in line 1

Comment: oh! change `String` to `int` in first line.

Comment: But now the int cannot be applied to string, and in line 2 your operator cannot be applied. Thank's for your help!

Comment: I have no errors any more but it doesn't work. I have also tried a toast

Comment: How many times have you opened the app ? It should be launch alertDialog on 4th opening.

Comment: More than 7 times. But I also use a Splashscreen. So first the SplashScreen.java ist lauched, and 3 seconds later MainActivity.java is launched. Does that matter and have you tried it?

Comment: There needs small change. change `appLaunchedFor++` to `++appLaunchedFor` .

Comment: It works, but now it is shown eyery time after 3 launches

Comment: I gave you rough work dude. BTW add `getSharedPreferences("app_info", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("counter", ++appLaunchedFor).commit();`  after your `alertDialog.show()`.

Comment: Just unistall app then install again. nothing happaning because counter has reached to 4 so alertdialog will not trigger anymore. it need to be reset again, so uninstall then install again.

Comment: Thx. Works finde and I understood the logic

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), since it's simple and you said in the comments you've already used it.

You can do that by subclassing the `Application` class, incrementing a counter inside `MyApplication#onCreate()` and saving it in the `SharedPreferences`.

**Note:** This is not 100% certain. If the user clears the app's data, your counter will be lost. To prevent that, you can use private databases such as [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and [Realm](https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android/).

Comment: "if the user clears the app's data", every kind of data will be lost except for those which were saved to [external storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). As "private databases" can't be saved to external storage (which is not private), they too would be erased.

Comment: @0X0nosugar well, that's not entirely correct. Both SQLite and Realm **can** be saved in external storage ([SQLite source][1], [Realm source][2]). In that case, he'd need the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.
  
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373863/how-to-store-sqlite-database-directly-on-sdcard
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551664/how-to-move-my-realm-file-in-sd-card

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I dont know how i should save it in sharedpreferences. I am a beginner in Android

Comment: Well, I don't like the idea of storing sensitive data in external storage (not even encrypted sensitive data) but I suppose a counter is not exactly sensitive. And one could store a countdown and clean up after the third time - to keep the user's device tidy ;-)  So okay, it's possible.

Comment: @Seilbahn SharedPreferences use a key-value approach. You can set a key (say "COUNTER") to your counter and when your Application class' onCreate() is called, you can retrieve that counter (using the specified key), increment it, checking if == 3 and save it, if necessary.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I agree. Even though it is possible, creating a database that will remain there even after the app is uninstalled is bad. But, in this case, it seems to be some sort of coursework. In that case, SharedPreferences should be fine.